# Am I allowed to link to the movie posters from IMDB?

Tags: copyright, images, imdb

I am planning on making a site that deals specifically with movie trailers. I would like to know if I am allowed to link to the movie posters from imdb and display them on my site.

I am mainly concerned with copyright laws, and if I can get sued for this.

I am not actually hosting the images, I'm just linking to them.

Comment: Matt are you still working on the trailer site? Did you use imdb poster link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TheMovieDB.org](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/terms-of-use) & [RottenTomatoes.com](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/page/read/API_Terms_of_Use) provide APIs that let you grab posters [under relatively liberal conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787808/is-there-any-online-free-movie-information-apis).

Generally speaking, you have to provide attribution to the site you're getting the images from and not archive any content.

Comment: Rotten Tomatoes [no longer provides](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/184496) reasonable sized posters through their API. The size of the current thumbnails seems to be around 54x80 pixels, which is unacceptable.