# Is it problematic to use movie posters on a blog hosted in europe?

Tags: images, copyright

I would like to use poster images of movies like "fais pas ci, fais pas ca", "plan coeur" etc. (mostly french movies), but I am worried about the copyright.

And I already found [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39197/am-i-allowed-to-link-to-the-movie-posters-from-imdb), however I am not looking for an API, the posted link there is broken and I feel like my situation is different because the website is hosted in Europe.

Thinking this should not be a problem for the movie creators since this is promotional material and actually helps them to generate more revenue, I am still wondering what's the best way to legally use such pictures?

Answer (score 1):

TheMovieDB still offers an API, which [provides posters too](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images). I see no any legal problem with displaying them, not in Europe, not elsewhere.